# LongListSelector interaction breaks when a popup is open in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, popup, windows-phone, longlistselector

To dynamically place some content on a page in a Windows Phone 8 project, we use a popup with a grid to host the content.

When this page contains a `LongListSelector` control, the Tap interaction to stop scrolling no longer works. Swiping up and down works as expected.

The issue can be reproduced very easily by starting with a new Databound app and adding this piece of code in the page constructor:

```
private Popup p;

p = new Popup();
Grid grid = new Grid();
grid.Width = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
grid.Height = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;
p.Child = grid;
p.IsOpen = true;
```

Using this code you can make the `LongListSelector` scrolling but a Tap does no longer work to stop the scrolling.

Has anyone seen this issue and found a solution or might this be a known issue with the `LongListSelector`?

Answer (score 0):

The invisible `Grid` that you're putting over the `LongListSelector` (actually the whole page) is capturing the tap event and because the popup is not part of the visual tree the event doesn't bubble as you're expecting.

The anomaly here is that you can actually interact with the LLS at all.

The real question here isn't why this happens but why you'd do this? Obviously your reproduction is very simple but it's to a point that makes no sense.

What are you ultimately trying to achieve?
There are almost certainly more appropriate alternative ways to achieve your end goal.

Comment: The popup is used to do light dismiss in the same way this is offered in the Windows Runtime. The popup contains some content that can put into an expanded state. If it is expanded a tap outside of the content should close the expanded content. I believe the invisible Grid should not interfere with the interaction at all because it does not handle interaction events by default.

Comment: @JLaanstra I still don't understand why you need this in a Popup though. Note that the WinRT UIFramework is different to Silverlight (which WinPhone uses) and will do some things differently. Also borrowing UI metaphors and behaviours from one platform and applying them to another isn't always a good idea. Unfortunately your vague description of what your trying to achieve hasn't helped make it clearer the end goal of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to detect touch interactions outside of a control in a popup. I can not make it more clear than this. While I tried to do that I encountered the above problem, which seems like a bug to me. The behavior I am looking for is similar to popup.IsLightDismissEnabled on Windows 8. I do not think that borrowing this UI behavior is causing problems on the phone.

Comment: @JLaanstra My question was why you were using a Popup in the first place? Could you not use something else? Or add a background to the grid with a slight opacity to the Grid so it will capture the interactions.